# Visual Studio Online - download code and then disconnect

Tags: c#, tfs

I am using this code to download the latest version from our Visual Studio Online repository:

```
NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
BasicAuthCredential basicCred = new BasicAuthCredential(netCred);
TfsClientCredentials tfsCred = new TfsClientCredentials(basicCred);
tfsCred.AllowInteractive = false;
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(serverURL), tfsCred);
tpc.Authenticate();

var versionControl = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
versionControl.NonFatalError += versionControl_NonFatalError;

var files = versionControl.GetItems(vSOLproject, VersionSpec.Latest, RecursionType.Full);
foreach (Item item in files.Items)
{
var localFilePath = GetLocalFilePath(item, vSOLproject, folderDestination);
switch (item.ItemType)
{                    
    case ItemType.File:
                  item.DownloadFile(localFilePath);
                  break;
                    case ItemType.Folder:
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(localFilePath);
                        break;
                }
}
```

This works fine. But how do I remove the connection to the source control so that I can edit files without checking them out?

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood the concept of a SourceControl (TFS)? You are only allowed to edit a file if it is checked out.

Comment: @TomB That's not true at all. The problem is that he's not mapping a local workspace and retrieving it, he's just pulling down files directly out of source control without a workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map a local workspace and work out of that. Here's a simple example that maps all of the team projects in a team project collection to a local workspace, then downloads the files:

```
var tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://localhost:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"));
var vcs = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
var result = vcs.TryGetWorkspace(@"C:\MySourceCode") ??
                vcs.CreateWorkspace(new CreateWorkspaceParameters("MyWorkSpace")
{
    Location = WorkspaceLocation.Local,
    Folders = new []
    {
        new WorkingFolder("$/", @"C:\MySourceCode", WorkingFolderType.Map, RecursionType.Full)
    }
});

result.Get(VersionSpec.Latest, GetOptions.GetAll);
```

However, it probably makes more sense to work within the IDE. One of the strongest points of TFS is its integration with Visual Studio.

Comment: This is part of an automated build process so can't work within the IDE. Basically some of the files need to be manipulated outside the source control hence the question. So if I create a local workspace like you suggest - would that work?

Comment: Just read up on the local workspaces and it sounds exactly what I am after. Thanks for your help.